# Trouble with Jekyll (stylesheet not included?)

Tags: css, yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to fork a Jekyll theme and upon building the Github Page, I get a different page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emq3p.jpg

**than the original**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX90P.jpg

The `baseurl` in `_config.yml` is changed accordingly to the instructions, no further changes made. Only the branch `gh-pages` was modified, which I used as the source for building the Github Page. 
I tried forking repositories that were forked from the original repository, but I get the same result. The issue looked like it failed to include a certain stylesheet, so I moved the file `_includes/css/style.css` to a different location, which led to a slight improvement but the color values from `_config.yml` and images in `assets` were still missing.

My implementation:

- Source: [Github Link](https://github.com/CerboSpace/solid-jekyll)
- Demo:  [Link](http://cerbospace.github.io)

Original:

- Source: [Github Link](https://github.com/st4ple/solid-jekyll)
- Demo: [Link](https://st4ple.github.io/solid-jekyll/)

Changes made to `_config.yml`:

```
    - url: "http://st4ple.github.io"
    + url: "http://cerbospace.github.io"
```

**Edit:**
changed the repo name. Also removed the collaborators-only edit rights for now, just in case.

I just tried building the site locally, because there were other questions indicating it worked locally but not on Github Pages. Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Asking us to look at some images and decipher what is different is likely not going to get you a proper answer.   We can only guess without actual code and those guesses will most likely be wrong.  Please provide the actual code as you have it as well as a clear description of the exact challenge you face. For example you might provide the .yml before and after your changes as well as .

Comment: Please re-read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more guidance on how you may address this by updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking through the files in the `_site` directory of the local build, I found that Jekyll replaces/overwrites my stylesheet in `_includes/css/style.css` with a different one. I have no idea where this new `style.css` comes from, but I found a workaround by using a custom `style.scss` and including my stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use https://ricostacruz.com/til/relative-paths-in-jekyll or add github-metadata `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/style.css?v=" | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">`